# Unable to add raw values to the insert into SQL Server select query

Tags: sql-server

This query is throwing an error

> VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CONSUMPTIONQTYMASTER] ([shop], [fgModelCode], 
                                          [VINNumber], [SerialNumber], 
                                          [consumptionQty], [itemCode], 
                                          [itemDescription], [grnNumber],
                                          [sku], [lotNumber], 
                                          [serial], [uom], 
                                          [vendorCode], [vendorName])
VALUES (10, '7FASTDOM15R05S2D0302', 
        'TIEV1-DPWO-0100', 'test serial 100', 
        2, (SELECT 
                STORE.itemCode, STORE.itemDescription, STORE.grnNumber, 
                STORE.sku, STORE.lotNumber, 
                STORE.serial, STORE.uom, 
                STORE.vendorCode, STORE.vendorName
            FROM 
                STORE 
            WHERE 
                STORE.SKU = '7B0101000032h22003'));
```

Comment: Use shop, fgmogel code etc with select clause

Comment: Please do NOT use an image to supply important information in your question, Those cannot be search, the text cannot be directly accessed, and are prone to removal over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VALUES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instructiona has a specific syntax and you need to follow its rules.

This specific case is covered by [Limits and Restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations-and-restrictions) paragraph

You can rewrite your query in this way:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CONSUMPTIONQTYMASTER] (
    [shop], 
    [fgModelCode], 
    [VINNumber], 
    [SerialNumber], 
    [consumptionQty], 
    [itemCode], 
    [itemDescription], 
    [grnNumber],
    [sku], 
    [lotNumber], 
    [serial], 
    [uom], 
    [vendorCode], 
    [vendorName]
)
SELECT 
    10, 
    '7FASTDOM15R05S2D0302', 
    'TIEV1-DPWO-0100', 
    'test serial 100', 
    2, 
    STORE.itemCode, 
    STORE.itemDescription, 
    STORE.grnNumber, 
    STORE.sku, 
    STORE.lotNumber, 
    STORE.serial, 
    STORE.uom, 
    STORE.vendorCode, 
    STORE.vendorName
FROM 
    STORE 
WHERE 
    STORE.SKU = '7B0101000032h22003'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery in the VALUES entry is messing things up. Change instead to something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO [table] ( [column a], [column b] ... )
SELECT 'Static Value A', 'Static Value B', ... -- other columns
FROM [source-table]
WHERE [condition]
```